# Why don't we actively strugle to provide the highest LET particle radiation therapy, maybe with manganese, fluorine, nitrogen, iron, or osmium?

Tags: radiation, radiology

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3885128/ 
I am a cancer patient since 16, a medical student aiming for radiation oncology and subsidiary MSc&Phd in radiophysics. I am actually autistic but with no mental retardation. So I need the questions to help me explain myself, why some events seem paradoxical and exactly what information I need. I extensively and thoroughly read ncbi, pubmed and textbooks concerned with my question in hand.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Medical Sciences. A couple of things.... First, I count 7 questions in your question, so basically you're asking for a textbook. You need to narrow your question down to a single question. Second, we require some degree of prior research here. And finally, most of your question belongs in the Physics exchange. So in addition to narrowing the question, you need to tell us what you've done to try and answer this on your own, and then split out the questions that are physics and ask them in the Physics exchange.

Comment: My one question is if any particle would have greater L.E.T than carbon and if so which would have the greatest? My other questions are subsidiary to the main question. I am a cancer patient since 16, a medical student aiming for radiation oncology and subsidiary MSc&Phd in radiophysics. I am actually autistic but with no mental retardation. So I need the questions to help me explain myself and exactly what information I need. I extensively and thoroughly read ncbi, pubmed and textbooks concerned with my question in hand.

Comment: Okay, that's great that you've done a lot of prior research, but my other points remain. You need to edit this question down to a single question and ask only about the medical aspects. Particle physics is off topic here but on topic in the Physics exchange. You can edit your question by clicking the 'edit' link just below your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I cannot see how a can edit my question down to a single question with the same meaning as now. Can you please help me with editting it, by telling which parts exactly do you dislike and explicitly giving me the best alternative(to your liking alone) I appreciate you have no legal obligation to reason your decisions specifically and thoroughly but you would help me very much indeed if you did so. May you please explicitly help me? Thank you earnestly! My question is not on particle physics but on particle radiation therapy

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you're trying to ask. All I can suggest is deleting everything in the post except for a single question, and make sure the one you don't delete has a medical aspect. Then add a single link to one of the places you've been reading about your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I still needed a body.

Comment: The body can be the research behind your question. It doesn't need to be more than that.

Comment: I think it will be very difficult to find an answer here as it is a very niche question in an uncommon field of practice.  You might have better luck in biology or physics.  But these sort of "what about..." conjecture questions (which are certainly important and often drive future research!) are not well suited to Stack Exchange. 
 Perhaps they are best asked at your medical school institution, as you may build on discussions from there.

Comment: @DoctorWhom which conjecture of mine is sort of "what about..."? I asked why do we not do something!

Comment: Sorry if my wording wasn't clear.  You ask "why not do it X way" and suggest several potential options. These sort of speculation / discussion questions are valid and good questions, but not well suited to this StackExchange site.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I lost detail by removing subsidiary questions. Linear Energy Transfer is a measure of how much a procedure deals damage to the target instead of surrounding tissue. I asked if the therapeutic effect was monotonically increasing with L.E.T. Supposing it where why wouldn't we struggle to provide the highest L.E.T what are the trade-offs?

Comment: This may be better, depending on whether the question is answerable - which I do not know, as this is not my specialty.

Comment: @DoctorWhom but I am only asking why don't we struggle to provide the Highest LET! I am asking why don't we do a single thing. I don't suggest many ways.